# twitter api on posting tweet did not work, instead returning 401

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, twitter-oauth

what i want is i want to post some tweet, so i 
follow these tutorial [login](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/05/login-with-twitter-using-oauth.html)
then second part [tweet on user behalf](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/06/tweet-on-behalf-of-user-from-aspnet.html)

so i followed those tutorials, i was able 
to show the tweet login page, and was able to get the
access token, but somehow when i tried to post tweet,
it did not work, instead returning 401 unauthorize error
with this detail :

```
{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}
```

i have searching over the internet and found that a lot of possibilities
that might cause this error, i have been stug on this for 3 days,
it would be great if u can point out what i do wrong?

FYI :
below is the OAuth header that i generated to post a tweet

```
OAuth oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A50696%2FAdminSetting%2FTwitCallBack",
    oauth_consumer_key="SwPB3B8bZMwgmDL3pEWxxxxx", 
    oauth_nonce="4604227", 
    oauth_signature="AWalU%2BMCmNEAeL4gbTlJliL5hbI%3D", 
    oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
    oauth_timestamp="1427791470",
    oauth_token="1049524608-6umHjgrPXKwGH7xvxWMcIm6C7YyTv9XxXWxxxxxx", oauth_version="1.0", status="test"
```

and also i have set my twitter app to request write and read permition.

thx before.

Comment: Are you using https when posting to twitter?

Comment: @dzl yes i use https, except for callback url.